# running model.evaluate many times results different accuracy and loss value tensorflow 2

Tags: conv-neural-network, data-science, tensorflow2.0

I have trained a CNN network using `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, label))` to create the dataset. training went well but evaluating the model on test dataset results different values every time without changing anything in test dataset or the network and I am not using any `Dropout` or `Batchnormalization`:

If necessary my code:

```
 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Input((1,30,30)),
    Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", name="c1", data_format="channels_first"),
    Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", name="c2", data_format="channels_first"),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(1,1),padding="same", name="m1", data_format="channels_first"),

    Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", name="c3", data_format="channels_first"),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(1,1),padding="same", name="m2",data_format="channels_first"),

    Flatten(),
    Dense(256, activation="relu", use_bias=True),
    Dense(5,  use_bias=True)])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_data, verbose=1, validation_data=valid_data, epochs=20)


model.evaluate(test_data)
```

Comment: do you train the model every time? or just evaluate the model gives a different result

Comment: just evaluating.